# Android error parsing BluetoothDevice

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am running my Android 3.0 app under Eclipse Kepler. It uses bluetooth. When I try run it on my phone, I get the following error:

```
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad descriptor: LLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice;;
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:347)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:328)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1116)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad descriptor: LLandroid/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice;;
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.rop.type.Type.intern(Type.java:351)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.rop.type.Type.internClassName(Type.java:415)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:289)
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx     ... 41 more
...while parsing cst 0009 at offset 000000eb
...while parsing android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice$1.class

[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-01-10 12:16:31 - AIR_Activity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Nothing showed up on google for me. I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was being caused by having jmockit.jar in my classpath. It was colliding with other libraries and killing the deployment, so the error had nothing to do with the actual problem.

I figured out the issue by using intellij.