# Where do I find com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser?

Tags: java, android

I'm having some issues deploying from my eclipse Kepler environment to my Android phone. The problems appear to be in class: com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.

I am trying to find the source for this class for Android 4.1.2. I have downloaded all of the sources I can find in my android sdk. I did a find for this class name. I've explored directory tree and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I googled the classname and did find: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik2/+/master/dx/src/com/android/dx/cf/cst/ConstantPoolParser.java but have no idea what version this is or how to navigate to the proper version.

I then found the site https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+refs which looks like it has what I need. Does anyone know which of these is the source for build tools 19.01?

Comment: You can't access that class because it it not part of the public framework. It is part of dalvik which runs your code. What problem do you see with that class?

Comment: I wondered about that. So dalvik is not open source? Doesn't it run as part of Android and Android is open source?

Comment: Dalvik is open source, you found the source already :) Dalvik is roughly what the `java.exe` tool does on a PC, it executes the code.

Comment: My mistake, it is actually part of the [`dx`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487268/android-dx-tool) tool which converts a Java `.class` file into Android consumable `.dex` bytecode. If you see an error there you / your Java compiler has created a class file that is not understood by `dx`, maybe you've compiled a Java 7 type `.class` file which `dx` does not understand.

Comment: So how can I find the version of the source I'm looking for? I only have java 6 on my computer, so I can't have compiled anything java 7.

Comment: You don't have that source on your system. It is the source that is used to compile the `dx` tool which is then shipped as part of the Android SDK. Can you show the error you get? The solution to your problem is most likely not related to that file.

Comment: The error is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050452/android-error-parsing-bluetoothdevice. I'm trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-building/4.1.2/android-building/2rkEoKMnhzU/3s-GgaU_NT0J Which led me here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/android-4.1.2_r1

Thanks for the help.